# $.getScript with username and password

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know if there's anyway for $.getScript to bypass any sort of password/username, because i'm password protecting some scripts on my webserver and I need to somehow get $.getScript to use a username and password when "getting" the script.

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify your question?

Comment: Just use a normal GET request and build the script tag in the success function.

Comment: comment 1: Basically i wanna "get" a script from a protected page.
comment 2: Thats cool and all, but im not sure how i would make it enter a username and password

Comment: Assuming you are using basic auth, there are headers for username and password

Comment: explain more about problem

Answer (score 0):

That need to be done on the server, if you embed a password in your JavaScript then your users will see the password. It all depends on what server you are running and you will need to allow unauthenticated access to the script you don't want to have to protect.

Comment: i know that, which is why the script is on my webserver, and im using tampermonkey to inject it to the website im visiting.